# grid: How to force sizes of grid.layout when unit is "npc" instead of "inch"?

Tags: r, grid-layout

Why are the sizes (for the regions (2,2), (2,4), (4,2), (4,4)) in the following plot not respected by `grid.rect()`? In other words, why do the the drawn rectangles not perfectly match these regions? With the units being "inch", this works (but I would like to use "relative" coordinates).

```
require(grid)

inch <- FALSE # TRUE

d <- if(inch) 5 else 1
pspc <- d*c(0.3, 0.3) # width, height of panels
spc <- d*c(0.05, 0.05) # width, height of space
axlabspc <- d*c(0.1, 0.1) # width y label, height x label
labspc <- d*c(0.05, 0.05) # width label boxes, height label boxes

par. <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
gl <- grid.layout(5, 5, default.units=if(inch) "inches" else "npc",
                  widths=c(axlabspc[1], pspc[1], spc[1], pspc[1], labspc[1]),
                  heights=c(labspc[2], pspc[2], spc[2], pspc[2], axlabspc[2]))
grid.show.layout(gl)
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))
for(i in 1:2) {
    for(j in 1:2) {
        pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=2*i, layout.pos.col=2*j, name="foo"))
        grid.rect()
        upViewport()
    }
}
par(par.)
```

Comment: Your example needs a definition for `nx` and `ny`.

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grid.show.layout(gl, vp=viewport(width=1.25, height=1.25))` and it works.